# Cohomologie Etale

Tags: etale-cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topology

Is there an English translation available for Deligne's Cohomologie Etale (Arcata) that is now part of the SGA 4 1/2 ?? Atleast for the first two sections - Grothendieck Topologies and Etale Topology.

Comment: Variations of this question get asked periodically:
Has xyz, where $xyz\in\{A,C,E,F,G,S\}$, been translated?
The answer is usually, "No but mathematical French is not that bad".

Comment: Actually, Deligne's french is particularly nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is hosted on the [wonderful webpage](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/) of J. Milne:

[Étale cohomology: starting points](https://www.jmilne.org/math/Documents/DeligneArcata.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Much of SGA 4(1/2) is translated in Lei Fu, Étale cohomology theory.